Lookup a value (in column) based on "Accumulated Sum" (or total) of QTY shipped column

Staff-A [Column A, row 2] "Fills" a Location with 50 QTY [Column B, row 2] at 12:00 [Column C, row 2]
From 12:05 to 12:30 [Column H] QTY are depleted from the Location [Column G]
...a total of 50 QTY have been depleted at 12:30 (from 12:05 to 12:30)
HOW DO I: "Lookup" the QTY [Column G] and "Intelligently" return the Time value (of 12:30) in [Column H, row 8]
NOTE: 5 QTY at 11:00 [Column G & H, row 2] is ignored - because they were depleted 'before' 12:00 [Column C]
ALSO, HOW DO I: "Lookup" the QTY [Column G] and return the Time value (of 12:20) in [Column H, row 6] ...for Staff B [Column A, row 3] who "Filled" the (same) Location with 20 QTY [Column B, row 3] at 12:15 [Column C, row 3]
VLOOKUP returns the first value (eg: 11:00) - however, I'm not sure how to tell VLOOKUP to 'sum' up the values (to equal the QTY filled) ...and then return that time value




Item Code
Final DateTime
Employee Number
CubeRpln
Deplete Time

Item Code
Final DateTime
CubeRpln




1079613
4/3/2024 22:40:00
741044472
2.60
4/4/2024 3:04:35

1079613
4/3/2024 18:43:26
0.26


1079613
4/4/2024 2:20:00
741023458
1.56
4/4/2024 3:04:33

1079613
4/3/2024 21:18:22
0.26


1079613
4/4/2024 2:40:00
741044472
1.04
4/4/2024 3:04:32

1079613
4/3/2024 22:36:53
0.26


1083320
4/3/2024 14:00:00
741047084
2.52
4/3/2024 23:27:50

1079613
4/4/2024 0:02:08
0.26


1083320
4/3/2024 22:00:00
741080713
2.52
4/4/2024 3:09:30

1079613
4/4/2024 3:04:29
0.26


1140915
4/3/2024 20:40:00
741024943
4.40


1079613
4/4/2024 3:04:30
0.26








1079613
4/4/2024 3:04:31
0.26








1079613
4/4/2024 3:04:32
0.52








1079613
4/4/2024 3:04:33
0.26








1079613
4/4/2024 3:04:34
0.26








1079613
4/4/2024 3:04:35
0.52








1079613
4/4/2024 3:04:36
0.26








1079613
4/4/2024 3:46:37
0.52








1079613
4/4/2024 3:46:38
0.52








1079613
4/4/2024 3:46:39
0.52








1079613
4/4/2024 4:16:27
0.26








1079613
4/4/2024 4:16:28
0.26








1083320
4/3/2024 14:33:00
0.42








1083320
4/3/2024 14:33:04
0.42








1083320
4/3/2024 19:53:19
0.42








1083320
4/3/2024 19:53:25
0.42








1083320
4/3/2024 19:53:35
0.42








1083320
4/3/2024 23:27:50
0.42








1083320
4/3/2024 23:29:55
0.42








1083320
4/4/2024 0:59:37
0.42








1083320
4/4/2024 3:09:30
1.26








1083320
4/4/2024 3:09:35
0.42




https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ymOatgYSTbPsoUddv2sOxtHhJHNtNmz4ldvCJm1uVE/edit
Added More "RealWorld" Data

Indicated in Column G whether [The Result] is correct

The formula 'appears' to be looking for the exact number, there are instances where the QTY doesn't surpass the Filled ...until it is "Partially" surpassed (in the next row)
I have edited the (original) question above ...to show the result of the formula [Column D] ...and then adjusted the QTY [Column N] ...so that the time when 50QTY is achieved was at 12:35

@rockinfreakshow - I've added some "Real World" data (this time) - wondering if the additional "variable" >> Item Code [Column B & Column H] is causing the confusion
Hope the Table Generator & the Anonymous Blank Sheet Maker ...help?

@rockinfreakshow - Added more "Real World" Data (to the shared sheet) - seems like the blank (or null) "Result" when QTY [column J] is less than the "Filled" amount [Column E] ...works properly when it's the last row, however, when more Data is added, another value is added [to Column F] ...when it should remain blank?

@rockinfreakshow "troubleshooted" and after I threw a whole day's worth of real world "Data" at it ...the formula works


UPDATED FORMULA:
=iferror(let(Σ,filter(I:J,H:H=B2), Λ,xmatch(C2,index(Σ,,1),1),
     Ξ,chooserows(Σ,sequence(max(1,rows(Σ)-Λ),1,Λ)),
     xlookup(E2,scan(,index(Ξ,,2),lambda(a,c,a+c)),index(Ξ,,1),,1)))



Please see "Edits" (or clarifications) above

Try the updated formula

Wow, here's hoping I'll be able to figure out how the formula works  ...for now, it works - thank you.

Its kinda tough to create formulas if you provide test data via screenshots since it lacks the means for us to test the formula on! For future 1 You can easily share test data via this table generator. Just paste the sheet data cells in this generator→press submit→then copy-paste the data here in the question as a table. 2 You can also share a test sheet using this anonymous blank sheet maker & is super recommended

Will do  ...totally appreciate all the feedback, the table generator makes a lot of sense - thank you for your timely responses.

...okay, I've added some "Real World" data (this time) - wondering if the additional "variable" >> Item Code [Column B & Column H] is causing the confusion

Updated the formula; do test it out

Testing ...standby ⏳

Tested - almost there  ...my fingers are crossed that I'll (be able to) understand what the formula is doing when all the bugs are worked out

check the iteration in column_K

standby ⏳ ...adding more data, hmm, getting a "CHOOSEROWS" (Error) - I'll post a picture in the question section.

LOL, as I was explaining the "CHOOSEROWS" error (above) - I looked at the Shared Sheet (to grab a print screen) ...and noticed it was gone.
Wow @rockinfreakshow ...you're fast

just wrapped the whole formula within iferror() to avoid the no-match-errors

"troubleshooted" and after I threw a whole day's worth of real world "Data" at it ...the formula works
